# return the sum of all integers

Tags: java

Program should return sum of all the numbers in a string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "1a2b-3c";
    data=data.replaceAll("[\\D]+"," ");
    String[] numbers=data.split(" ");
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
        try{
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The sum is:"+sum);

}
```

So for the above input, it should return sum as 0 ==> `(1+2 - 3)`

But my above code returns 6. What is the right regex for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you should do it

```
String data = "1a2b-3c";
int sum=0;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
while (m.find()) {
  sum+=Integer.parseInt(m.group());
}
```

Comment: no need for try/catch as the regex validates with the find is the string is indeed a number !

Comment: The method parse(String) is undefined for the type Integer

Comment: That is weird because when you look at the documentation at : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group()
group returns the string which was identified in find

Comment: this was a bad mistake on my end !

Comment: this still gives me 6

Comment: @david you need to get rid of spaces first to create `-3` instead of `- 3`.

Comment: can you explain the regex if possiblke?

Comment: The -? looks for negative numbers inside a string and will match them. the d part represents digits inside the string.The + as d+ looks for digits greater than simply 0-9

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to do this.

```
 if(numbers[i - 1].equals('-')){
           sum-=Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
 } else 
   sum+=Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the split tool on your String, splitting every symbol individually into an array , then just add the numbers with parseInt and you're done. No need for a pattern here I think.

Comment: if its a long string like a document, this computation will take a long of time (O(n)) where n is every symbol found with the splitting as you mentioned. I don't think it's a good idea except when in situations like the one the OP just gave.

Comment: Good point , but it should work fine for something like this.

Comment: Like I said, if this was the current situation. But usually, in question we give sample data that should match what we really want. Because sometimes, it concerns sensible data that cannot be shared with the public. Which is why I said your answer would be good if the situation the OP was in was exactly something that looks like this. Otherwise, the solution should be discard. I don't mean it's not good or functional, but it's brute force and should be refine in order to have a lesser impact on the overall performance of the software.